# Sound not working, from "Dummy Output" to "HDMI/DisplayPort-Built-in Audio" Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, hdmi

Hello everyone and a good morning to you all. I have recently installed ubuntu and have encountered a big problem my sound is not working. At first my audio was not outputing any sound and only showing "dummy output" but by running

> **$ echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**

> **$ echo "options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**

> **$ echo "blacklist snd_soc_skl" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**

and reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio along with force reloading them the output now changed to "HDMI/DisplayPort-Built-in Audio" however the sound is still not working.
When I run `$ alplay -l` it shows my sound card is detected showing the output

> ****** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
> card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
> Subdevices: 0/1
> Subdevice #0: subdevice #0**

How do i fix this ? please help :(